# How to use german umlaute in Mac os x X11 xterm

Tags: x11, max, xterm

I have a macbook pro with german keyboard layout.
In the X11 xterm application, when I type umlaute like ä,ö,ü,ß, then they don't show up. And ß shows the history like the up-arrow.
On the other hand if I start emacs in x11 (not in the xterm) then everything works fine.

How can I configure X11 xterm to type all characters?

And yes, I checked the "follow system keyboard layout" checkbox in the preferences panel.

Thanks,
alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, works on my box. What is your LC_CTYPE? Mine reads LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8, and i have checked .inputrc with no umlaut specialties found.

Comment: strange, it is not set. Do you set it in the .profile or in the .bashrc?

Comment: aaahhhh. I set it in the .profile, and now it works fine, as expected. Thanks for the quick tip!!

Comment: In my .bashrc actually, and I tear my profile settings since years from one machine to another, so I cannot tell anymore if this should be set per default by some OS X system preferences mechanism.

Comment: Always Welcome! Could you then on some occasion accept the answer (by clicking on the tick mark)? ;-)

Comment: I still have one problem: if I set LC_CTYPE, then cmd-x types a "ø". I have disabled key equivalents in the preferences. BTW I use emacs, thats why I need the cmd (Meta) key.

Comment: Hence I am one of the last vi dinosaurs (at least that's how it feels some time :) I am missing any experience on the subject, but I found this one: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems#toc15 Does it help?

Comment: hmm, some heavy tricks... I think I will use my emacs.app instead of starting it from a terminal or xterm. Thaks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I just had the opposite problem... my X11 had been on German Umlaute for quite a while, and I didn't recall how I managed to do that. Now I am working all with QWERTY layout, so I wanted to remove the Umlaute again.

Seems I had a custom ~/.Xmodmap file that X11 was reading. After I removed this file, I had the English layout again. So probably you need to search for .Xmodmap and put an appropriate file in your home folder.